# How to install/uninstall/update a homemade Python module?

Tags: python, module

I wrote a small module that has this structure:

```
~/
   a/
      b/
         foo/
            __init__.py
            foo.py
            bar.py
```

Each time I use my module - I have to go in its folder and start my interactive session:

```
$ cd ~/a/b
$ ipython

In [0]: from foo import *
```

I would like to easily make available my module globally on my PC. Do I need to structure it as package with a `setup.py` and execute `python setup.py install` after each change on my module?

Another solution that I don't really like is adding the following to my `ipython` profile:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("~/a/b")
```

Or modifying my `PYTHONPATH`:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$HOME/a/b
```

Comment: I think the last two options (adding new path to be searched during import) are best for you. What's bad about them?

Comment: Probably nothing bad about them. It was just a feeling there is always a better option than modifying my `user` config.

Comment: The only other option that comes to mind is to install a package and then modify those installed files. But it feels dirty.

Comment: Why not use `python setup.py develop`, then you don't need to reinstall after every change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, install it globally as a python package or use a virtualenv

Comment: What do you mean by `install it globally`? Does it mean I have to run `python setup.py install` each time I modify my module?

Comment: Yes, it means you would have to run that each time. By globally I assumed you were referring to your local python installation where libraries are able to be imported with the default PYTHONPATH. Mine will install here for example: '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages'. Your best solution if you don't want to run setup.py every time is to use a virtualenv.

Comment: So I have to read a bit about `virtualenv`. I've never used it.

Comment: It's very easy, the best guide is probably this one: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: In newer Python versions, you likely want venv instead of virtualenv:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder-in-python may be a good read.